# Response Content-Type was 'null'. Rest assured exception

Tags: java, testing, rest-assured

I have problem with rest-assured. I'm reciving the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot parse object because no supported Content-Type was specified in response. Content-Type was 'null'.
```

My rest-controller look like below

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping(ApiUrls.SESSIONS_API)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SessionsApi {

    private final SessionsService sessionsService;

    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public List<SessionDto> sessions(@AuthenticationPrincipal CryptoUser user,
                                     @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "false") boolean includeExpired) {
        log.info("User sessions of user [id {} username {}]", user.getUserId(), user.getUsername());


        return sessionsService.getSessionsOfUser(user, includeExpired);
    }
```

and the test

```
SessionDto[] sessionDtos = given().mockMvc(mvc)
        .log().all()
        .header("Accept","application/json")
        .get(ApiUrls.SESSIONS_API)
        .then()
        .extract()
        .as(SessionDto[].class);
```

is rest assured logs I get

```
Request method: GET
Request URI:    http://localhost:8080/api/sessions?includeExpired=true
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: includeExpired=true
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Content-Type=application/json
                Accept=application/json
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:           <none>
```

I tried to add produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE in getmapping but anyway is didn't work. Am I missing something ? Thread is not even getting into controller method

Answer (score 1):

If your content type is null you can try something like this

```
given().mockMvc(mvc)
    .log().all()
    .header("Accept","application/json")
    .get(ApiUrls.SESSIONS_API)
    .then()
    .contentType(isEmptyOrNullString())//This is where you handle null
    .extract()
    .as(SessionDto[].class);
```

Also this link might be useful: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/636

Answer (score 0):

> Add produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE in
>   **@RequestMapping** instead of **@GetMapping**.

Replace

```
 @RequestMapping(ApiUrls.SESSIONS_API)
```

With

```
@RequestMapping(value = ApiUrls.SESSIONS_API, produces = {
    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
```

Comment: No, it didn't work. Anyway RestController is producing by default JSON